# What function invokes the "navbar-toogle" button in bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('#navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $("html").click(function() {
     //OPTION 1
   document.getElementById("navbar-collapse").classList.remove('show');

   //OPTION 2
   //$('#navbar-collapse').hide(); 
      
  //OPTION JAIME
  //$('#navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
 });

 $('#navbar-collapse').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
 }); 
});
```

```css
.bg-ecs-white{
 background: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-brand {
  color: #34219e;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-ecs .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ff2069;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #34219e;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #ff2069;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #00e1e1;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-toggler {
  color: #ff2069; 
  border-color: #34219e; 
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 32, 105, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

/***************NAV-SUBLINK**************/
@media (min-width: 992px){
 .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-sublink {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
 }
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-sublink {
  color: #ff2069;
}
.navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-sublink:hover, .navbar-ecs .navbar-nav .nav-sublink:focus {
  color: #ff2069;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-sublink, .navbar {
 padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

 .dropdown-menu {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #c6ffff); /*to right,*/
  border: none;

 }

 .dropdown-toggle::after,
 .dropup .dropdown-toggle::after {
  content: none;
 }
 /*botones submenú navbar*/

  .btn-link {
   color: #34219e; 
  }

  .btn-link:hover {
   color: #ff2069;
   text-decoration: none; 
  }
#intro {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-ecs-white navbar-ecs fixed-top scrolling-navbar"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="logo">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
</div>
    <button id="btnTog" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sec 1</a>
            </li>          
          </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="intro">
      <br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>
        <p class="text-white text-center">
CONDITION
the menu can only be opened with the button, to close, when the user touches outside the menu</p>
<p class="text-white text-center">1.open menu  2.touch background blue 3.open menu 4. :(</p>
        <br> 
      </div>
      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to hide the navbar menu when a user clicks outside of a specific div. The function of identifying the click outside the div responds well, but the navbar does not respond again as it would like.

What I am trying to do, is that when the user presses outside the div, he makes the call to the same function that hides / shows the navbar menu. And I would like to know:
What function invokes the "navbar-toogle" button in bootstrap4?

I am trying all these options, but I can not find the key, each of them gives a different error.

## Jquery / JavaScript

```
    $('#navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
$("html").click(function() {

        //OPTION 1
        //document.getElementById("navbar-collapse").classList.remove('show'); // The "navbar-toogle" button does not respond

       //OPTION 2
       // $('#navbar-collapse').hide(); // Problem, the style = display: none remains active (there is no way to remove it)
            //$('#navbar-collapse').css('display','none'); //I also try to assign the manual value of none first, and once it is hidden, it performs the following function (IT DOES NOT WORK)
        //$('#navbar-collapse').removeAttr('style'); //If I add this line, style is completely removed, and the hide () function does not respond

//OPTION JAIME  
      $('#navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle'); //The menu opens always touch where the user touches. OPTION NOT VALID

        // OPTION 3 
        //document.getElementById("btnTog").classList.add('collapsed'); //Behavior OK
        //$("btnTog").attr("aria-expanded","false"); // DO NOT CHANGE THE VALUE, it always stays "true"
        //document.getElementById("navbar-collapse").classList.remove('show'); // OK Behavior - Problem: If I press the Hide / Show Menu button (btnTog) It does not hide

       // OPTION 4, 5, 6, ... TESTING OTHER VARIANTS without success
        //$("navbar-collapse").toggle();
        //$("#navbar-collapse").css("display","");
        //$("#navbar-collapse").css('display','');

        //$('#navbar-collapse').get(0).style.display='';
        //$('#navbar-collapse').css('display',null);
            //getElementById("navbar-collapse").removeAttribute("style");
            //getElementById("navbar-collapse").removeAttribute("display");
            //getElementById("navbar-collapse").removeAttribute("none");
        //document.getElementById("#navbar-collapse").style.display = null;
        //document.getElementById("navbar-collapse").classList.remove('display');

    //document.getElementById("navbar-collapse").classList.add('collapsing');
});

$('#navbar-collapse').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

## PHP / HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-ecs-white navbar-ecs fixed-top scrolling-navbar"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="logo">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
</div>
    <button id="btnTog" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sec 1</a>
            </li>          
          </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Holy crap, I had the biggest brain fart. I don't know why I was thinking dropdown when it was clearly collapse.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#methods

```
$('#navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

This is probably what you need.

I also have a codepen that I created:

https://codepen.io/jamierytlewski/pen/YgJzEj

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but look what happens in Option 2
/ Problem, the style = display: none remains active (there is no way to remove it)

Comment: You need to remove option 2. Option 2, if you want it to display again you have to use ```$('#navbar-collapse').show();``` I would just replace option 2 with the code above.

Comment: That option is not valid. If I put show (), then it is never hidden. The problem is in a style that automatically displays none, and I have no way to make it disappear.
  I will try to upload the code to the console, so that the error is shown

Comment: That option is NOT VALID. The menu can only be opened from the button and closed from anywhere.

Comment: Look at the codepen. It's working. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Now that it works 100%
Thank you very much Jaime